# differences among these gems jquery-pjax pjax-rails rack-pjax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pjax

plz help me. i am new to ruby on rails. now i would like know about differences among jquery-pjax, pjax-rails, rack-pjax gems. And also want to know good basic start up tutorial for pjax. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A great start up tutorial for PJAX is Railscast #294 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax).

The differences between the pjax_rails and rack-pjax are basically that rack-pjax gives you a much larger amount of control over what is actually using pjax across your site, while pjax_rails just makes every link pjax activated.  If you use pjax_rails, you won't need to install jquery-pjax, if you use rack-pjax you will need to install jquery-pjax.  I highly suggest watching the Ryan Bates video, it rules and you will get a great start.  Also, github typicall offers very great documentation on most gems and things of the sort, I've provided links below:

JQUERY-PJAX : https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

PJAX_RAILS : https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails

RACK-PJAX : https://github.com/eval/rack-pjax

And one more time:

RAILSCAST #294 : http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax